RHEL 9 passwd Authentication token manipulation error
RHEL 9.4. Running passwd accountName comes back with:
passwd Authentication token manipulation error.

journalctl -xe
gkr-pam: couldn't update the login keyring password: no old password was entered

/var/log/secure
Dec 17 11:08:28 server1 sshd[228669]: Using arbitrary primes is not allowed in FIPS mode. Falling back to known groups. 
Dec 17 11:08:29 server1 sshd[228669]: PAM unable to dlopen(/usr/lib64/security/pam_pwhisory.so): /usr/lib64/security/pam_pwhisory.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

/var/log/messages
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/pwhistory_helper from read access on the file /proc//stat

I have an /etc/shadow file, and it looks good
I have not tried in single user mode which I have seen as some solutions, would I have to do single user mode every time I want to change a password?
Can I provide any more information to help, or does anyone have a suggestion.
Thank you!
I tried using seahorse through the GUI, and it was successful, however not all of the boxes have a gui and I am only to SSH to them. I have tried overly strict passwords. On changing the password, I have tried logging in with it, and it was not successful. Ran sudo mount -o remount,rw. The server has been rebooted.
